# Ubuntu 16.04 with Xfce desktop and nautilus cause theme issue

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus, themes, xfce

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with Xfce4 desktop environment beside to the Unity.
I use nautilus as default file manager. When I click on the home icon on the desktop or use any folder from the files in the bottom panel, the desktop wall paper image is replaced with the Ubuntu default wall paper. In addition, the right click on the desktop context menu contents are changed too.

Is there any solution for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution but want to report that I experience exactly the same here. Some weeks ago I was searching the internet but found nothing really helpful. It is because nautilus does more than just being a file manager. Because of that I tried Thunar.

At office, the default OS is Ubuntu. But I am not a big fan of unity, therefore using Xfce...

Comment: Probably, I may follow your suggestion about Thunar. However, I will supply it with custom actions to allow file search. Indeed, missing file search in Thunar by default, is the cause that made me using Nautilus.